# Wheel alignment from OBD parameters

Tags: obd-ii, steering, alignment

Can I calculate wheel alignment from OBD parameters. Car is Hyundai i10, and it doesn't give any Steering Alignment/ Steering Position data.
The only method to check the alignment is to let the car move as you keep your hands off the steering wheel and watch it drift to one side. But, can this be detected while driving from an OBD?

Comment: The wheels can be way out of alignment and it will still drive straight.

Comment: Lets consider one wheel is misaligned. Then it will not drive straight. Can I calculate then? @HandyHowie

Comment: Wheels usually come out of alignment when hitting holes or curbs. When this happens, any sensor could equally get out of alignment with the real angle of the wheel, so any adjustment based on the sensors could make the wheel alignment even worse. If you are in doubt, go to a specialist, in my country the price is around €75.

Answer (score 6):

When you say OBD i'm assuming you mean generic data. The answer is outright NO. OBD generic data has no parameters that the alignment can be gleamed from.

If the car has a steering wheel angle sensor then maybe you could tell if something is wrong. This data would be available in manufacturer specific. If the angle has been off for a long time at high speed then the alignment may be off. But that is really it. You can't tell if it's the caster, camber or toe that is out and by how much.

Comment: To my knowledge the only parameter even close to this is steering wheel angle, but this is used to provide input for stability programs, then only on some vehicles (manufacturer/model dependent). There is nothing in the vehicle, as you rightly stated, which accounts for the caster/camber/toe-in parameters which make up for the alignment ... there definitely aren't any sensors used towards this end, either.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, the OBD-II standard does not require manufacturers to provide this information.

That said, some manufacturers may make steering angle information accessible through make-specific cables. This is usually done to give dealerships the ability to calibrate or recognize a replacement sensor.

Even if this information was available, you would need a means to evaluate the angle and orientation of each wheel. Most wheel alignment shops use special tools for this job.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. There is no way to electronically measure wheel alignment. Even if a manufacturer implemented a sensor to measure the wheels angles, any mechanical deformation would make the readings erroneous.

Comment: What mechanical deformation are you talking about?

Comment: Suppose as an example that the sensor measured the angle between the hub and the lower control arm. This would have to assume that the arm remained in the correct position. If the arm got bent slightly backwards after an accident, a "correct" reading on the sensor would probably coincide with a significant toe out.